# Bootstrap tooltip not working with .replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple `<div>` tags in my HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="lblTest well">Label 1</div>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 2</div>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 3</div>
```

and I am trying to set bootstrap tooltips to all the divs by looping like this:

```
$('.lblTest').each(function (i, n) {
    var $element = $(this);        

    //-- Add the data attributes required for tooltip
    $element.attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
        .attr('data-placement', 'bottom')
        .attr('title', 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i + 1));

    //-- initialize all the tooltips
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

This is working fine as you can see in this [**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/pot43fj1/)

But, when I use `.replaceWith()` to replace all the `<div>` tags with `<a>` the tooltips doesn't seems to be working. My code:-

```
$('.lblTest').each(function (i, n) {
    var $element = $(this);        

    $element.replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<a/>', {
            html: this.innerHTML,
            class: this.className,
            href: '#'
        });
    });

    //-- Add the data attributes required for tooltip
    $element.attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
        .attr('data-placement', 'bottom')
        .attr('title', 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i + 1));

    //-- initialize all the tooltips
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Updated [**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/pot43fj1/1/)

I also checked the Chrome developer tools and it seems that the data attributes were not added in this case. How can we resolve this issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done:

```
$element.replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<a/>', {
        html: this.innerHTML,
        class: this.className,
        href: '#',
        'data-toggle':'tooltip',
        'data-placement':'bottom',
        'title':'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i + 1)
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pot43fj1/5/)

---

Instead of setting new attributes to the var `$element` place all the attributes to the new element in the replace method.

Answer (score 2):

Note: when you use `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` in the `.each()` loop you're really initializing the current element, and the one(s) before (**AGAIN**). A better approach would be to use `this`: `$(this).tooltip();`

Another approach would be just to use `.attr( obj )` but with `attr: function` on the title like so:

```
$('.lblTest').attr({
    'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
    'data-placement': 'bottom',
    'title': function(i) { 
        return 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i+1);
    } 
}).tooltip();
```

```js
$('.lblTest').attr({
    'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
    'data-placement': 'bottom',
    'title': function(i) { 
        return 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i+1);
    } 
}).tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 1</div>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 2</div>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 3</div>
```

**AND**, once you replace the current div, the variable `$element` is pointing to null and therefore the data attributes are not added. See resulting html: `<a class="lblTest well" href="#">Label 1</a>....`. You can do [**add the data attribute within the replace**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/pot43fj1/9/) or [**predefine the `a` element before replacement**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/pot43fj1/8/)  or replace the divs like so:

```
$('.lblTest').replaceWith(function(i) {
    return $('<a/>', {
        'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
        'data-placement': 'bottom',
        'title': 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i+1),
        'html': this.innerHTML,
        'class': this.className
    });
});
$('.lblTest').tooltip();
```

```js
$('.lblTest').replaceWith(function(i) {
    return $('<a/>', {
        'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
        'data-placement': 'bottom',
        'title': 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i+1),
        'html': this.innerHTML,
        'class': this.className
    });
});
$('.lblTest').tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 1</div>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 2</div>
<div class="lblTest well">Label 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pot43fj1/7/

Your $element is reference to old element, before replace, so you need new selector, i guess...

```
 $('.lblTest').attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
      .attr('data-placement', 'bottom')
     attr('title', 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your referencing the old element, set the data attributes all in one go like below

```
$('.lblTest').each(function (i, n) {
    var $element = $(this);        

    $element.replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<a/>', {
            html: this.innerHTML,
            class: this.className,
            href: '#',
            'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
            'data-placement': 'bottom',
            'title': 'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i + 1)
        });
    });

    //-- initialize all the tooltips
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Here is a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pot43fj1/6/)

Answer (score 0):

`replaceWith()` will always return old content so you have to update your `$element` value.

Check this out its working as you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/pot43fj1/4/